# export an environment variable from python

Tags: python, export

How can I export an environment variable from Python?

```
# I want to export a variable in python the same way you would in bash 
export my_var="foo"
```

```
# The variable can be set in Python but it won't stay outside of the python session since it's not exported.
os.environ['my_var'] = 'bar'
```

Comment: What python IDE are you using? In Jupyter Lab you can just set the environment variable  with `os.environ['my_var'] = 'bar'` and never need to set it again. In PyCharm you set it by editing your configurations.